# Why are inline div behaving this way inside p

Tags: html

In the linked example, I have a text and a paragraph which each contain `span` and `div` elements.
Although all the `div` elements have the `display: inline;` style applied, the first `div` from the `<p>` starts on the next line.

Why is that ?

here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7HAPp/1/

I copied the code here:

```
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et <span>i'm a span</span> parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. Nulla consequat massa <div>i'm an inline div</div> In enim justo, 
rhoncus ut, <div>i'm an inline div</div> imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam
dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.


<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et <span>i'm a span</span> parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. Nulla consequat massa <div>i'm an inline div</div> In enim justo,
rhoncus ut, <div>i'm an inline div</div> imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam 
dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
```

Comment: It doesn't do that in Chrome 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Also, does the page render in standards compliance mode or in quirks mode?

Comment: I checked on Firefox 21, Chrome 24, Safari, Opera and IE 9. Given that they all render the same thing, I'm pretty sure it's not a browser bug. Anyway, I got my answer here, Thanks Eli.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`div` inside `p` is invalid markup.  When the browser encounters the `div` element it auto-closes the `p` tag and starts the new `div`.

Comment: Probably the case in whatever browser he is using. That's not happening, however, in mine (Chrome 24.0.1312.57 m).

Comment: @crush: Are you sure you're checking the first div in the paragraph? It's _third_ div in the example text.

Comment: @crush, on my Chrome (26beta), that *is* happening. The issue is as described in the question, and there is even a blank line before the `div`. When you look at the document in Developer Mode (F12), you can see the implied `</p>` tag before the `<div>` tag. The blank line is really the bottom margin of `p`. And at the very end, the homeless `</p>` has implied a start tag `<p>` before it. The point is that CSS settings cannot affect HTML *parsing*, which causes the `p` element to be terminated.

Comment: You know what, I was looking at the wrong part of the output. I see now that it is happening.

Comment: and the spec that literally explains this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html